# How to show a push-notification when the application is open(foreground), when OnMessage is triggered?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im use Flutter and Firebase Messaging.
I im configure Firebase like in example: 
`firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: ...
      onLaunch: ...
      onResume: ...
    )`
But i wanna see push-notification even when app is open. 
Roughly speaking onMessage should work like onResume. 
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        showNotification(message);
        print('on message $message');
      }




  showNotification(Map<String, dynamic> msg) async {
    var android = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your channel id',//channel id
      "your channel name",//channel name
      "your channel description",//channel desc todo set all this right
      icon: 'mipmap/launcher_icon'//add your icon here
    );
    var iOS = new IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platform = new NotificationDetails(android, iOS);


    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .show(0, msg['notification']['title'], msg['notification']['body'], platform);


  }
```

I used [flutter_local_notifications: ^1.2.2](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to show local notification foreground.

Additionally, if you are implementing for IOS don't forget to ask for notification permission.